# Swap characters between strings Haskell

Tags: string, list, haskell

if i say i have two strings or character lists,

```
list1 = ["c","a","t"]
 list2 = ["d","o","g"]
```

and if i read a string using Input Output `"ct"` and pass it to the function,the function should return `"dg"`.

Please give me any idea about such a function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would consider taking those two lists, zipping them together, use `Data.Map.fromList` to create a lookup Map, then map over the input String and use the Map to work out what to replace them with.

Comment: For a nice intro to `lookup` and `Data.Map`, see http://learnyouahaskell.com/modules#data-map

Answer (score 3):

I'll first assume `list1` and `list2` have type `[Char]` (i.e. `String`), since that's what your text seems to indicate (your code has them as `[String]`s -- if you really want this, see the generalized version in the addendum).

If you `zip` the two lists, you end up with a list of pairs indicating how to translate characters. In your example, `zip list1 list2 = [('c','d'), ('a','o'), ('t','g')]`. We'll call this our *lookup list*. Now consider the function [`lookup`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-List.html#v%3alookup):

```
lookup :: Eq a => a -> [(a, b)] -> Maybe b
```

In our case, we can specialize this to

```
lookup :: Char -> [(Char, Char)] -> Maybe Char
```

so we have something that takes a character and a lookup list and returns a substituted character if the input character is in the lookup list (otherwise a `Nothing`). Now we just need to glue the things we've found together: We essentially need to map `\c -> lookup c lookupList` (more elegantly written as `flip lookup`) over the input string while *throwing out* any characters not found in the lookup list. Well, enter [`mapMaybe`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Maybe.html#v%3amapMaybe):

```
mapMaybe :: (a -> Maybe b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

It does exactly what we want. Now your function can be written as

```
replace :: String -> String -> String -> String
replace list1 list2 = mapMaybe ((flip lookup) (zip list1 list2))
```

You'll need to import `Data.Maybe`.

**Addendum, for when you understand the above:** Observe how what we did above had nothing to do with the fact that we were working with lists of *characters*. We could do everything above with lists of *any* type for which equality makes sense, i.e. for (lists of) any type which is an instance of the `Eq` typeclass (cf the signature of `lookup` above). Moreover, we don't have to translate from that type to itself -- for example, each character above could be sent to say, an integer! So really, we can write

```
replace :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [b] -> [a] -> [b]
replace list1 list2 = mapMaybe ((flip lookup) (zip list1 list2))
```

and now our function works as long as `list1` is a list of something for which equality makes sense. Replacement of characters just becomes a special case.

A quick example:

```
> replace "cat" "dog" "ct"
"dg"
> replace "cat" [1,2,3] "ct"
[1,3]
```

Comment: oh nw i got that logic, ya it will be a huge favor if u can provide more .

Comment: as in ill be taking input from user a string then ill convert tha characters in the string with my own [char] list.. something like a Cesar encryption.

Comment: *** Expression    : replace
*** Expected type : Eq a => [a] -> [b] -> [a] -> [c]
*** Inferred type : Eq a => [a] -> [b] -> [a] -> [b]

Comment: Note that ivanm's answer (using a `Map`) will perform better than my list-based solution. I deliberately avoided introducing the (better-suited) `Map` data structure to keep it simple, but keep in mind ivanm's solution is better.

Comment: @user1194367: Works fine here... are you trying to apply `replace` to something? If so, what?

Comment: `replace1 is the function name,ERROR file:.\aplcHaskell.hs:57 - Inferred type is not general enough

*** Expression    : replace1
*** Expected type : Eq a => [a] -> [b] -> [a] -> [c]
*** Inferred type : Eq a => [a] -> [b] -> [a] -> [b]
----------------------------------------------------------
enc13:: IO()
enc13 =
 do
  putStrLn"\t Enter Sentence to Encript"
  instr <- getLine
  let outStr = replace1 instr
  putStrLn outStr

replace1 :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [b] -> [a] -> [c]
replace1 alfa1 alfa2 = mapMaybe ((flip lookup) (zip alfa1 alfa2))`

Comment: @user1194367: What do you mean by "replace1 is the function name"?

Comment: replace1 is the function name,
`ERROR file:.\aplcHaskell.hs:57 - Inferred type is not general enough
 *** Expression : replace1
 *** Expected type : Eq a => [a] -> [b] -> [a] -> [c]
 *** Inferred type : Eq a => [a] -> [b] -> [a] -> [b] 
---------------------------------------------------------- 
enc13:: IO() 
enc13 = 
 do 
  putStrLn"\t Enter Sentence to Encript" 
  instr <- getLine 
  let outStr = replace1 instr 
  putStrLn outStr 

replace1 :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [b] -> [a] -> [c] 
replace1 alfa1 alfa2 = mapMaybe ((flip lookup) (zip alfa1 alfa2))`

Comment: @user1194367: Oh.. try to explicitly add the type signature (as in my answer).

Comment: Well, I didn't provide code as the question asked for *ideas*... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

For two string you may do as follows:

```
patt :: String -> String -> String -> String
patt (x : xs) (y : ys) p'@(p : ps)
  | p == x = y : patt xs ys ps
  | otherwise = patt xs ys p'
patt _ _ [] = []

main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn $ patt "cat" "dog" "ct"
```

Comment: This only walks down the lists of substitutions once, so `patt "cat" "dog" "ctc"` gives an incomplete pattern match error, while I think it's supposed to return `"dgd"`.